# How to store user-specific documents in firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Flutter and Firebase Firestore to build a note-taking app. I'm trying to store each new note under the signed-in user in Firestore but the notes are visible to all users.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the time, I suggest you watch this fully. It explains clearly and precisely how to make a Note making app with a clean architecture.
[Reso Coder's DDD](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLB6lc7nQ1n4iS5p-IezFFgqP6YvAJy84U)

But, if you just want to get to the firebase security rules and the implementation, then see this:
[Create, Update, Delete Notes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMXczqzyQms&list=PLB6lc7nQ1n4iS5p-IezFFgqP6YvAJy84U&index=17)
and
[Firebase Security Rules](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86dqg6ryx_M&list=PLB6lc7nQ1n4iS5p-IezFFgqP6YvAJy84U&index=32).

You might wanna see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgR9MNCFYGA&list=PLB6lc7nQ1n4iS5p-IezFFgqP6YvAJy84U&index=27) to get the updated code after firebase's update in flutter.

Comment: Only videos... what about good ol’ text articles? :(

Answer (score 0):

You can make Collections using the unique user-ID given by Firebase at the time of Registering User!
you can get the user-ID of the current user by executing `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid`
and store the notes as Documents in specific user's Collection.
At the time of Retrieval you can use the `Stream Builder` and give the `Stream` as `collection` of `Current User's user-ID`.